# Paypal Integration with laravel 6 using Paypal API

Tags: laravel, paypal, laravel-6

This is my first time using Paypal on my ecommerce project. After a failed attempt using a package that I saw, I decided to read Paypal documentation and see if i could get it done myself. So far, I have gotten the Access Token but I don't know where to go from here since I could not find the end point api to make payment. Please can anyone suggest what I should do or direct me to the right link that explain the procedures of working with Paypal with Laravel 6

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
[
 'auth' => [
            '<username>', '<password>','basic'], 
             [
                'headers'        => [
               'Accept' => 'application/json', 
               'Accept-Language'=> 'en_US', 
               'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
             ], 
             ],
             'body' => 'grant_type=client_credentials'
              
             ],  );
             $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

             $access_token = $data['access_token'];
```

Comment: https://www.positronx.io/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel/ Try this article. It uses laravel-paypal library (https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal) . Also you can follow the readme in the library github repository. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I used the version 1.0 [srmklive/paypal:~1.0] but I could only see the Sandbox paypal nvp/soap api credentials, I couldn't not see the live credentials. I followed procedures but I could not find the API Access on my Account settings. I also tried to use  [srmklive/paypal:~2.0] but I am lost, since I don't know the right method to call after creating instance Provider

Answer (score 0):

Create two routes on your server that implement the `v2/checkout/orders` API to 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

You can use the Checkout-PHP-SDK (which automates getting the access token) or implement the HTTPS APIs directly as you are doing in your sample, either solution (with or without the v2 SDK) is completely fine.  *Just don't use anything based on the older v1 SDK or the "v1/payments" API specifically, as those are deprecated for new integrations*

With those two 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction' routes implemented on your server, the recommended flow to use for customer approval is: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

It offers the best, most modern web experience as there is no redirection away to an approval_url -- instead your site is kept loaded in the background and the PayPal login opens over it, which is very much desirable.